# Spark with aws sign v4 issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My spark (2.4.0) batch writes data to s3 , looks like its use aws s3 sign v2 which needs to be changed as Aws require to move to v4 sign (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html)

in order to do it we need to do the following :

1- add aws.s3.endpoint when we initialize spark conf like

```
 val hadoopConfiguration = sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
    hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key",xxx)
    hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key",yyy) 
    hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
```

2- force use of sign4

System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENFORCE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true")

3- upgrade Aws client  above 1.11, I used

```
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
 <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
 <version>1.11.199</version>
```

After deploying spark job with kubernetes, task run and wrote data to s3  but it crashes and returns an error that Aws sign is not match

I open s3 bucket logs and search for the error and my best guess is that after uploading a file there is a crash in the executor and another executor is trying to upload the same file and he signs it with v4 but the sign does not match (maybe timestamp not equal)

from reading, I understand I need to upgrade spark to Hadoop 3.2, how to to it? Well, I did it and wanted to share the steps in order to help others:

***Solution :***

Steps that needed to be done :

in order to compile spark with hadoop 3.2

1) Download spark source from github

2) I used tag v2.4.0 as master version failed to work well on kubernetes

3) Add in pom file new profile in hadoop profiles section

```
 <profile>
             <id>hadoop-3.2</id>
             <properties>
               <hadoop.version>3.2.0</hadoop.version>
               <curator.version>2.12.0</curator.version>
               <zookeeper.version>3.4.9</zookeeper.version>
             </properties>
           </profile>
```

4) run --> ./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-3.2 -Dhadoop.version=3.2.0 -DskipTests clean package

5) run --> ./dev/make-distribution.sh --name fyber-spark --tgz
   -Phadoop-3.2 -Dhadoop.version=3.2.0 -Pkubernetes

now you will have spark 2.4.0 with Hadoop 3.2 ready to use

6) as I use kubernetes I also needed to modify the dockerfile

Add -->

```
ENV AMAZON_SDK_VERSION=1.11.199
ENV HADOOP_AWS_VERSION=3.2.0


# adding s3a support
RUN wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/${AMAZON_SDK_VERSION}/aws-java-sdk-${AMAZON_SDK_VERSION}.jar -P /tmp \
&& wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/${HADOOP_AWS_VERSION}/hadoop-aws-${HADOOP_AWS_VERSION}.jar -P /tmp




RUN  cp /tmp/aws-java-sdk-${AMAZON_SDK_VERSION}.jar /opt/spark/jars \
&& cp /tmp/hadoop-aws-${HADOOP_AWS_VERSION}.jar /opt/spark/jars
```

make sure you have "nss"

```
RUN set -ex && \
    apk upgrade --no-cache && \
    apk add --no-cache bash tini libc6-compat linux-pam nss && \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark && \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark/work-dir && \
    touch /opt/spark/RELEASE && \
    rm /bin/sh && \
    ln -sv /bin/bash /bin/sh && \
    echo "auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid" >> /etc/pam.d/su && \
    chgrp root /etc/passwd && chmod ug+rw /etc/passwd
```

That is all now you can submit spark job and it supports s3a with s4 sign,
to make sure it supports v4 you can :

1. increase log level to debug for aws and verify s4 sign header exist
2. open s3 bucket logs and verify it write with s4 sign